# AutoTouch findImage function

Tags: ios, iphone, lua, autotouch

I wanted to make a madden mobile sniping bot. So I wanted to use the `findImage` function to find if a player has sold or not. Here is what I'm thinking.

[image: first image] [image: second image]

The first image would be my screen and the second image would be what image I'm trying to find, and if it find it it will tap on it. Here is my script:

```
local r = findImage ( "/images/auction.bmp" ,1, 1, nil, nil); 
if r == nil then alert ( "nil" ); 
else local n = 0;
    for i, v in pairs (r) do n = n + 1; 
end if n == 0 then alert ( "false" ); 
else 
    alert ( "true" );
    end
end
```

It runs but always returns false. So I was wondering if I'm using the `findImage` function right and if so why doesn't it return true?

Answer (score 0):

The `end` statement at line 5 closes the `for` loop and is directly followed by another `if` statement before the first one at line 2 has been closed.

Try ending both before issuing another condition.

I'd also recommend lowering the finding tolerance a little. A value of **1** is the most strict which means every single pixel must match precisely in order to be found. A value of ***0.8*** is just as accurate when finding such a large image yet still allows some fuzziness for improving detection.

Something like this should work.

```
local r = findImage ( "/images/auction.bmp" ,1, 0.8, nil, nil); 
local n = 0;

if r == nil then alert ( "nil" ); else 
    for i, v in pairs (r) do n = n + 1; 
    end
end

if n == 0 then alert ( "false" ); 
else alert ( "true" );
end
```